# Issue In Speechbrain with Hugging face

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, automatic-speech-recognition, speechbrain

I'm working on colab and I got this error while i was using  speechbrain.pretrained import EncoderDecoderASR
this is the data i used

```
minds_14 = load_dataset("PolyAI/minds14", "en-US",split="train")
```

this is the pretained model

```
asr_model = EncoderDecoderASR.from_hparams(
   source="speechbrain/asr-crdnn-rnnlm-librispeech"
)
```

this is where the problem occurs

```
for i in tqdm(range(0,length)):
    input_speech = minds_14[i]['audio']
    t0= time.time()
    transcription = asr_model.transcribe_file(minds_14[i]["path"],repo_type="PolyAI/minds14")
    t+= (time.time() - t0)
    all_predictions.append(transcription)
```

the problem :

```
HFValidationError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-daf03578985d> in <cell line: 8>()
      9     input_speech = minds_14[i]['audio']
     10     t0= time.time()
---> 11     transcription = asr_model.transcribe_file(minds_14[i]["path"])
     12     t+= (time.time() - t0)
     13     all_predictions.append(transcription)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py in validate_repo_id(repo_id)
    156 
    157     if repo_id.count("/") > 1:
--> 158         raise HFValidationError(
    159             "Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name':"
    160             f" '{repo_id}'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed."

HFValidationError: Repo id must be in the form 'repo_name' or 'namespace/repo_name': '/storage/hf-datasets-cache/all/datasets/51125457981586-config-parquet-and-info-PolyAI-minds14-efce24e3/downloads/extracted/cfd42a9443ffb9548ee39e3c64f8b512ca72b9ce5e2ea6b981d44ba6c7265ae8/en-US~JOINT_ACCOUNT'. Use `repo_type` argument if needed.
```

I tried to transcribe text with speechbrain.pretained